# SQL server management studio - email address as login

Tags: azure, ssms

I have an azure database I'm trying to connect to with my email address as the admin login. So in sql server management studio, the login prompt looks something like this:

[image]

When I attempt to login, I get an error:

> Cannot open server 'something.com' requested by the login.

This is clearly not my intention. How do I get it to treat my email address as simply the login name?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Appending @servername to the login allows it to look for the proper server.

So in this case, the login becomes name@something.com@example.database.windows.net